# Cannot upload images from web with upper case file extension such as JPG

Tags: support

Gives error about wrong format:
`Failed to upload image; the format is not supported`

But when I renamed the JPG to jpg from the URL, then it worked fine.

Example test URL: http://i1.minus.com/ibgWOvvwVX8nZ0.JPG

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with imgur and/or the site hosting the image - nothing to do with `.PNG` vs `.png`.

The error given is imgur indicating a bad request, trying to upload the image.

Trying to upload an image hosted elsewhere works just fine:

http://share.baeck.se/wallpaper/upload_83158.JPG

Comment: I first used the original image URL, didnt work, so i uploaded to minus.com, and still got same error. How is that possible?

Comment: @Rookie - good question. Could be that imgur is trying to upload them different ways, depending on extension. Could be that a corrupt image is on a caching proxy between imgur and them. I don't really know what is causing this.

Comment: Maybe the uploader could attempt to rename the JPG to jpg if it fails? :P

Comment: @Rookie - many sites are case sensitive. The issue here isn't about  `JPG` vs `jpg` (as my example shows). It is elsewhere, and we will be chasing it up with imgur.