# "The format is not supported", but it's a PNG image

Tags: support, bug, images

I can't upload this image to Imgur:

<s>http://image.prntscr.com/image/ad8a88c6c108491ab8bf5b10c71badc8.png

It's not even my image, I was editing in the H&I queue and it was [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37625682).</s>

For some reason, the above image now [uploads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsvT6.png). But the overall problem is not solved, since I can find plenty of PNGs that fail to upload, like this one:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png/280px-PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png

It gives me an error:

> Failed to upload image; the format is not supported

This may be the same unresolved problem here (but in other formats):

- ["Failed to upload image; the format is not supported" -unable to upload .gif from the web](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296715)
- [Cannot upload images from web with upper case file extension such as JPG](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272595)

I can upload *other* PNGs fine. I could upload one of the earlier ones (again) that Chrome had cached in autofill.

Comment: Content like that shouldn't be a screen shot anyway. Tell the OP they can Ctrl+C the code as well as the text of the error message instead.

Comment: ...meaning, if a message box like that has focus, then ctrl-c copies the entire contents of the dialog--no need to select any text.

Comment: This happens to me whenever I reference a PNG to be included as an image. Downloading the PNG and the uploading to SE works fine. Here's an example link that fails when inserting an image via link: http://image.prntscr.com/image/b426b8c5c5bc4364ad02418c2870d0eb.png

Comment: Could be that the server is blocking the request because it came from the wrong user agent (SE's)?

Comment: @Will: For real? TIL!

Comment: @Rob: Hah, I remember that question straight away!