# Why doesn't Stack Overflow allow images from lightshot (image.prntscr.com)?

Tags: bug, image-upload

I use [lightshot](https://app.prntscr.com/en/index.html) for taking screenshots. The program has the option of uploading images to their hosting site at `image.prntscr.com` which can be really useful. Unfortunately, Stack Overflow, and seemingly all the Stack Exchange sites, don't seem to support attaching images hosted on this site.

For example, I have an image at http://image.prntscr.com/image/9133a3d857d44fedbb4c57e332d69d95.png but if I try to attach that to a question on SO, I get the following error:

> **Failed to upload image; the format is not supported**

[image]

*To be clear, to upload the image, I simply clicked ["link from the web"](http://image.prntscr.com/image/2e4e18c1c507482293d077a0f5e6711b.png) and entered the URL for the image [in the provided box](http://image.prntscr.com/image/24c64eb646804757bed7a4bf1d5ff3f0.png) then clicked "Add Picture" and I get the error.

So I'm curious, why do images hosted on `image.prntscr.com` fail to attach to Stack Exchange websites?

Note that using the standard link syntax works fine to include the image, I'm just wondering why the uploader can't seem to handle the image and makes me manually link it or save the image locally then upload it.

Comment: i find that when this happens it's generally the other site, not `i.stack.imgur.com` that's the problem in which the other site is preventing hotlinking

Comment: @Memor-X fair, though the test at this site http://altlab.com/hotlinkchecker.php seems to indicate that this is not the issue here

Comment: I don't know the literal answer to your question but you can embed that image just fine by copying the image (just open it in another tab and Ctrl-C) and then Ctrl-V on the SO image wizard thingo.

Comment: @samgak excellent point, I didnt realize copy paste worked there. I'm still curious but thank you, that will certainly do as a workaround!

Comment: possibly related: [“The format is not supported”, but it's a PNG image](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324458/the-format-is-not-supported-but-its-a-png-image)

Comment: @PaulRoub indeed, same issue. Though it's being open for 8 months with no answer doesnt bode well for my curiosity ;)

Comment: Could be something about the headers / content type data prntscr is sending that imgur doesn't understand for some reason, though I don't see anything wrong. Gonna say it's a bug, the question is on which side :) Re-tagging so the devs on bug duty can investigate (and possibly pass a report over to imgur if it turns out that's the case)

Comment: maybe prntscr.com is blocking the transfer

Comment: @Memor-X uploading a file here is not hotlinking.

Comment: @TimPost Response headers look fine to me nothing weird in there.

Comment: @Lankymart Yeah, I checked too, earlier when I commented. It could be something much more basic like they simply fail to connect - I'll see if we can get this passed up to imgur.

Comment: Is it just me or is the response missing a content-type?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit only if it's a cached request.

Comment: @Lankymart: Oh yes.